# Error "upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while SSL handshaking to upstream" when trying to reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, signalr, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to get info from a web socket api and this needs to send an api-key as query string, so I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy to get a request and then add the api-key . After that send this request to the destination url (I don't want my users to be able to inspect the browser and find that key!!!)

Below is the request that my Nuxtjs app is sending :

http://my-site.com/ws/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1

and this is the nginx config in /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site.com :

```
server {
    listen          80;             # the port nginx is listening on
    server_name     my-site.com;    # setup your domain here

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/mysite;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|gif|jpe?g|png|woff2?|eot|otf|ttf|svg|js|css)$ {
        expires $expires;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";

        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location / {
        expires $expires;
        #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https: data:; base-uri 'self';";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy; # for generate.subFolders: true
        # try_files $uri $uri.html @proxy; # for generate.subFolders: false
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass https://external-api.net:7890/;
        set $args $args&apiKey=MYAPIKEY;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host external-api.net;
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error in error.log :

upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: my-site.com, request: "GET /ws/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://y.y.y.y:7890/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&apiKey=MYAPIKEY", host: "my-site.com"

How can I make this work ?

FYI : I don't use Docker ,Containers or load balancer. So I didn't put upstream in my nginx config.
Adding `proxy_read_timeout 3600;` to my location block didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. In my case, the problem was with the SSL. I've added the below lines to my NGINX location block configuration which I explained earlier in the main question :

```
proxy_ssl_name $host;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
```

and then reload NGINX :

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your question. It really saved me a lot of time